# Crash when retrieving last(6th) tab bar item when programmatically creating UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

```
- (void)setUpTabBarItems {

    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

    UITabBarItem *firstTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[0];
    UITabBarItem *secondTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[1];
    UITabBarItem *thirdTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[2];
    UITabBarItem *fourthTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[3];
    UITabBarItem *fifthTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[4];
    UITabBarItem *sixthTabBarItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[5];

}
```

I am programmatically creating a `UITabBarController` in `AppDelegate`. I have set up 6 view controllers before this method for the tab bar controller. In the above method, I intend to set the image and the title of the tab bar items.

There is a crash on the last line i.e., retrieving the 6th item of the `UITabBar` items array.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'`

I understand that the tab bar does not take more than 6 items so I am expecting the last button to be a `More` tab bar item. But I am unable to retrieve it.

But when I make a `UITabBarController` in `Storyboard` it works with many buttons. (taking 6 as maximum in this case, I don't need more)

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, if you add more than 5 tabs `UITabBarController` displays only the first four items and adds the standard More item as the 5th tab.
The items array will not contain more than 5 items anyway so if you try to access an index beyond 4 (which is the index of the More tab in this case) it will obviously crash.

If you need to perform operations on the More tab (selecting this tab for example), you can use `UITabBarController`'s `moreNavigationController` property.